# How do I fix the bug in the sudoSlider jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I am using the [sudoSlider](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/) jQuery plugin to make a html slider on my site. I have created buttons at the bottom that work as slide choosers but when it slides across it bounces back again. This is the site:

http://vermilionsite.com/RedFox/index.html

I can't figure out why this is happening!

Comment: Any change that you could accept the answer or come with some feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created SudoSlider

You have asked this question before, and i think i know what you mean now.

Is the problem that:

1: When you click one of the bottom buttons, the slider start the automatic slideshow again after about 6 seconds?

Or is it

2: that the slider doesn't stop after it reaches the 3. slide?

Solution to the first problem is to remove this line: "resumePause: 6000,"

Solution to the second problem is to remove this line: "resumePause: 6000,", and add the following to the SudoSlider configuration: "

```
afterAniFunc: function(t){if(t==3) sudoSlider.stop;}
```

Next time, be more specific.